# Is it possible to add sample description in HealthKit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I'm saving user's glucose in health kit, however I'm wondering if there is some way to store user description to that measurement too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom data to an `HKSample` by adding that data to the [metadata](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobject/1615598-metadata) dictionary when creating the sample.